# How to perform this replacement on a string only if a sequence of characters is separated from another substring by 2 or more words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

def person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, number_of_people_involved="singular"):

    if number_of_people_involved == "singular":
        assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(SINGULAR_PERS)", "le"
    elif number_of_people_involved == "plural":
        assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(PLURAL_PERS)", "les"

    n_or_more_words = r"\w+\s+\w+\s*" #pattern to match at least two words
    input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))\s*(" + n_or_more_words + r")(" + personal_pronoun + r")\s*\(\(VERB\)",
                        lambda m: (f"{m[1]} {m[2]} " + assumed_subject_of_sentence + f" {m[3]} ((VERB)"),
                        input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return input_text


# input string example:
input_text = "le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"

input_text = person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, "singular")
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

How do I make this program add `"(SINGULAR_PERS)"` in front of `"le"`, if and only if, there is no sequence `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))"` two or more words before the last occurrence of the string "le" (the same if there is never a sequence `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))` before `"le"`, since it is interpreted that there are no less than 2 words in between, if the first condition never appeared).

You would need to assign the `n_or_more_words` variable a regex pattern that indicates that at least 2 or more words are required (a word is understood as a sequence of characters with no spaces in between `\w+` ) between the last occurrence of a sequence `"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))"` and a `"le"`

Although this function does not give an error, for some reason it cannot modify the string since it does not identify the cases where it should make the modifications. What should I change to this function?

So after performing the replacement you get this output:

```
"(SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego (SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)ayudo)"
```

Comment: So you want to replace some text in `input_text` only if that text lives farther than 2 doors down from some other text. Simple. What is the input ?

Comment: What you want to do is match `(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\)(?:\s*(?!le)\w+){2,}\s*le)|(le)` https://regex101.com/r/HDMyIm/1 If Grp1 matches write it back without change. If Grp2 matches write back `(SINGULAR_PERS)` + `grp2` This allows you to move past the conditional content without changing it, onto the point past that content to start cheching again. This is the only option Python offers in their old re module. The newer regex module has morem better options.

Comment: @sln This is the input `input_text = "le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"`, and that input is different from the output that I am indicating in the question, this is the output `"(SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego (SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)ayudo)"`, because it adds in front of `"le"` in certain conditions that are indicated in the question

Comment: So using this line of code   `input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\)(?:\s*(?!le)\w+){2,}\s*le)|(le)", lambda m: (f"{m[1]} {m[2]} " + assumed_subject_of_sentence + f" {m[3]} ((VERB)"), input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`  could I get the correct output?

Comment: You have to specify why this input `((PERS)Marcos) le ` does not match `le` given your stated specs :   `if and only if, there is no sequence "(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))" two or more words before the last occurrence of the string "le"` since `((PERS)Marcos)` is 1 away. https://regex101.com/r/i1elSX/1

Answer (score 0):

Didn't mean to abandon you.

I've again looked at your question statement, code sample and before and after sample text.

Came up with something that might get you started.
This Python regex callback sample integrates into your function there and does a
substitution in the callback where:

If group 1 matched, it is written back no change.
This is because it found the `((PERS) ...)` and 2 or less words right after it,
which could contain the `le` string.
This guarantees more than 2 words will pass before the next `le` can be matched.

If group 2 matched, `assumed_subject_of_sentence` is prepended to the `le` that is sent back for the replacement.

`n_or_less_words` is used in the construction of the regex and is a variable (fixed at "2" for now).

`assumed_subject_of_sentence` is determined at function time *person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func* and is used in the replacement callback.

This is just an example of how to invoke a logical replacements and you
should be able to adapt it and the regex to accomplish your task.

Regex:  https://regex101.com/r/OyLNlR/1

Python code:

```
import re

def person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, number_of_people_involved="singular"):
  #
  if number_of_people_involved == "singular":
    assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(SINGULAR_PERS)", "le"
  elif number_of_people_involved == "plural":
     assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(PLURAL_PERS)", "les"
  def repl(m):
    if m.group(1): return m.group(1)
    return assumed_subject_of_sentence + r" " + m.group(2)
  #
  n_or_less_words = "2"  # Really means 0 - 2 words (no matter what, will be written back with '((PERS)..`)
  #
  input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\)(?:\s*(?!\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))\b\w+){0," + n_or_less_words + r"2})|(?<!\S)(le)(?!\S)",repl,input_text)
  return input_text

# input string example:
input_text = "le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"

input_text = person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, "singular")
print(input_text) # --> output
```

Output:

```
>>>
>>> import re
>>>
>>> def person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, number_of_people_involved="singular"):
...   #
...   if number_of_people_involved == "singular":
...     assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(SINGULAR_PERS)", "le"
...   elif number_of_people_involved == "plural":
...      assumed_subject_of_sentence, personal_pronoun = "(PLURAL_PERS)", "les"
...   def repl(m):
...     if m.group(1): return m.group(1)
...     return assumed_subject_of_sentence + r" " + m.group(2)
...   #
...   n_or_less_words = "2"  # Really means 0 - 2 words (no matter what, will be written back with '((PERS)..`)
...   #
...   input_text = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\)(?:\s*(?!\(\(PERS\)(?:\w\s*)+\))\b\w+){0," + n_or_less_words + r"2})|(?<!\S)(le)(?!\S)",repl,input_text)
...   return input_text
...
>>> # input string example:
... input_text = "le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"
>>>
>>> input_text = person_identification_of_personal_pronouns_le_and_les_func(input_text, "singular")
>>> print(input_text) # --> output
(SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego (SINGULAR_PERS) le ((VERB)ayudo)
>>>
```